# JNA can't find shared library on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, jna

I am writing an interface in Java which uses underneath library in "C".
Now, when I try to load the library specifying relative path, it cannot find the library.
If I give the absolute path, it works fine.

I want to know, is there something to do with relative and absolute path on MAc OS. Because same code works well on linux(even though I specify relative path on that).

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the system property `jna.debug_load` (pass `-Djna.debug_load=true` to your JVM) will result in console output indicating where JNA is looking for your native library.

Keep in mind you need to define `jna.library.path` to be the directory where JNA can find your library.  That value should be an absolute path.  If you're using something like `myapp/libs` then your operation is going to be dependent on whatever the process's current directory is set to.